# Issue while displaying "foreach" values

Tags: powershell, loops, while-loop, foreach, powershell-5.1

I have an powershell script which get's a list of customers from an json file, and then print it, based on what it typped until now.
But, even the "list" block being after the "userInput header", it display the list before it, why?

json example:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Example LTDA",
    "database": "SqlServer"
  },
  {
    "id": 321,
    "name": "ECOMMERCE SA",
    "database": "Oracle"
  }
]
```

script:

```
$customersJson = Get-Content "%jsonpath%\customers.json" | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { $_.name }

while ($true) {
    #Clear-Host
    [console]::CursorVisible = $false

    #Write-Host "DEBUG: `nfullString: $fullstring `nuserInput: $userInput `nFIM." -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host "Type the customer name:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host "> " -NoNewline
    Write-Host $fullstring -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $userInput = [System.Console]::ReadKey($true)

    if( $userInput.Key -eq "Backspace" )  { $fullstring = $fullString -replace “.$”      }
    elseif( $userInput.Key -eq "Enter" ) { return $fullstring                            }
    else                                { $fullstring = $fullString + $userInput.KeyChar }

    if(($fullstring.Length -gt 1) -and ($null -ne $fullstring)) {
        $customersList = $customersJson | Where-Object { $_ -match $fullstring } #| Select-Object -First 10

        Write-Host "____________________________`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGray
        foreach($customer in $customersList) {

            # Primeira letra maíúscula
            $customer = $customer.ToLower()
            $customer = $customer.Replace($customer[0],$customer[0].ToString().ToUpper())
            if ($fullstring -eq $customer) {
                Write-Host $customer -ForegroundColor DarkRed
            } else {
                Write-Host $customer -ForegroundColor DarkGray
            }
        }
        Write-Host "____________________________" -ForegroundColor DarkGray
    }

}

[console]::CursorVisible = $true

Write-Host "Typed customer: $fullString" -ForegroundColor Red
```

Display the customer list, after the prompt("Type the customer name") header, not before.

Comment: What's the relation between the JSON you've posted and the script? And what exactly are you referring to when you say "the userInput header"?

Comment: Sorry, it was not showing the first line "Get-Content" due to the code formatting.
This JSON is part of "customers.json".
Also, the "header" is the ``Write-Host "Type the customer name:`"` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the prompt after the customer list, move the `ReadKey` statement until after you've rendered the list:

```
$customersJson = Get-Content '%jsonpath%\customers.json' | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object { $_.name }

$fullString = ''
[console]::CursorVisible = $false

while ($true) {
    Clear-Host

    # 1. Write prompt header
    Write-Host 'Type the customer name:' -ForegroundColor Yellow

    # 2. Optionally write customer list
    if ($fullstring.Length) {
        $customersList = $customersJson | Where-Object { $_ -match $fullstring } #| Select-Object -First 10

        Write-Host "____________________________`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGray
        foreach ($customer in $customersList) {

            # Primeira letra maíúscula
            $customer = $customer.ToLower()
            $customer = $customer.Replace($customer[0], $customer[0].ToString().ToUpper())
            if ($fullstring -eq $customer) {
                Write-Host $customer -ForegroundColor DarkRed
            }
            else {
                Write-Host $customer -ForegroundColor DarkGray
            }
        }
        Write-Host '____________________________' -ForegroundColor DarkGray
    }

    # 3. Prompt for next char
    Write-Host '> ' -NoNewline
    Write-Host $fullstring -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $userInput = [System.Console]::ReadKey($true)

    if ( $userInput.Key -eq 'Backspace' ) { 
        $fullstring = $fullString -replace '.$'      
    }
    elseif ( $userInput.Key -eq 'Enter' ) { 
        return $fullstring                            
    }
    else { 
        $fullstring = $fullString + $userInput.KeyChar 
    }
}

[console]::CursorVisible = $true

Write-Host "Typed customer: $fullString" -ForegroundColor Red
```

Comment: I messed up what i meant with the order of each write-host, but the ReadKey statement right after the list is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much.

Comment: @JânioGentil you're welcome! Think of the `Clear-Host` as the start of your "print cycle" and `ReadKey()` as the end boundary - anything you want displayed has to happen within those two boundaries :)